# Offset-based Pagination Errors in Apollo-Client

Tags: pagination, graphql, react-apollo, graphene-python

Recently decided to transition my Relay Client for Apollo due to how pagination is handled. I need offset-based pagination for the application I am developing and this is better supported in Apollo.

While attempting to implement offset pagination per the Apollo documentation, http://dev.apollodata.com/react/pagination.html#numbered-pages but continue to get errors that my viewer is undefined.

[image]

This error references when I am accessing the data from props during render time and only occurs when I attempt to implement the fetchMore function. I have a feeling it has to do with my setup since I am using a `viewer` entry point in my GraphQL query but despite trying to modify the setup the error persists.

```js
... ... ...
105   props: ({ data: { loading, viewer, fetchMore }}) => ({
106     loading,
107     viewer,
108     loadMoreEntries() {
109       return fetchMore({
110         variables: {
111           offset: viewer.allSweeps.edges.length
112         },
113         updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
114           if (!fetchMoreResult) { return previousResult; }
115           return Object.assign({}, previousResult, {
116             viewer: [...previousResult.allSweeps, ...fetchMoreResult.allSweeps]
117           });
118         }
119       });
120     }
... ... ..
```

Edit 1:
So far it appears that this error is related to a lifecycle issue. Doing some debugging I've noticed that this pagination method has caused the initial prop to load without any data in the viewer when previous data was present while performing a simple query.

Hoping to use one of the React lifecycle methods to track down with this change occurs to see if I can assign the data to a variable. Still not sure if this method is set up correctly however. Will need to get data coming in and then attempt to paginate before I know for sure.

Edit 2:
Able to use componentWillUpdate to obtain fine-grained control over data being propagated. So that step is solved. Just need to investigate the actual pagination mechanisms now.

Answer (score 0):

So the two big pieces that I was missing here was that first, as noted above I needed to utilize componentWillUpdate to obtain finer control over the data flow.

More importantly though was I did not realize that the return value of updateQuery needed to be formatted like my schema and include __typenames.

Here is snippet of what that looks like,

```js
136         updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
137           if (!fetchMoreResult) { return previousResult; }
138           const newEdges = fetchMoreResult.viewer.allSweeps.edges;
139           return {
140             viewer: {
141               __typename: previousResult.viewer.__typename,
142               allSweeps: {
143                 __typename: previousResult.viewer.allSweeps.__typename,
144                 edges: [...newEdges]
145               }
146             }
147           }
```

The only thing is that fetchMore seems to be more targeted towards infinite pagination which isn't really what I'm going for. I could keep things a little simpler and just stick with stateful management of offset/limit and use simple queries to get the desired results. But there are some conveniences afforded here that I like such as fetchMoreResult which should be able to let me know the bounds of my data.

Hope this helps someone.